# eslint-plugin-react rule react/no-unknown-property false negatives on all props for threejs

Tags: reactjs, eslint, react-three-fiber

after installing the threeJS  I kept having the eslint-plugin-react rule react/no-unknown-property false negatives on all props for threeJS while trying to pass props..

[See error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxwxV.png)

I tried disabling eslint-plugin-react rule, but it wasn't the best fix

/* `"react/no-unknown-property": ["error", { "ignore": ["args"] }]`*/

Answer (score 0):

this package solved the issue for me [@react-three/eslint-plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chECc.png)

follow the instructions after installation

1. installing @react-three/eslint-plugin (`npm install @react-three/eslint-plugin --save-dev`)
2. Adding `"plugin:@react-three/recommended"` to the extend in eslintrc.cjs file
3. adding `@react-three` to the list of plugin.

[See solution here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chECc.png)